# Overriding package libraries in Google App Engine project

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework

I am writing a Google App Engine Django REST Framework project that uses external libraries through `requirements.txt`.
In one of the of files in a module installed in requirements.txt, I am manually editing some code there. How do I get GAP to use this modified version instead of original one.

The way I am doing this is installing the packages in a folder called `lib`, modifying the package inside it and then creating a file called `appengine_config.py` which contains this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```

But when I deploy it, it still uses the original package in requirements.txt. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE will use `requirements.txt` and install those libraries in the `lib` folder when you deploy.  That is just how it works.

Nothing prevents you from deploying code outside the lib folder.  You can structure your project like this:

```
GAE_folder:
-- app.yaml
-- requirements.txt
-- lib
-- my_app
-- my_custom_lib
```